# Can't associate an user's id to a task Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to create a to-do list web app using Laravel 5.7. For auth i used *php artisan make:auth*.

When I try to add a task, it just spits out error 500.

Also, displaying post that are manually created works.

**web.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'TaskController@index')->name('index');
Route::post('/tasks', 'TaskController@store');
Route::delete(' /tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@destroy');
Auth::routes();
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

**Task.php** (that Model just adds guarded and stuff to all other models)

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Task extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Up function (tasks)**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('text');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Task Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Task;


class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = Task::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('index', compact('tasks'));
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $task = Task::create([
            'text' => request()->validate([
                'text' => 'required|max:255'
            ]),

            'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);

        return response()->json($task->id);
    }

    public function destroy(Task $task)
    {
        $task->delete();
    }
}
```

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use request classes for validation of requests. So, your store method would look like:

```
public function store(TaskRequest $taskRequest){}
```

Second, add the following in your task model.

```
protected $fillable = [
   'text'
];    

public static function boot()
{
   static::creating(function($model){
      $model['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
   });
}
```

Third, your store method would like this.

```
public function store(TaskRequest $taskRequest)
{
   $task = new Task($taskRequest->all);
   $task->save();

   return response()->json($task->id);
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, but I get `Undefined index: 'App\Task'` when I try to show the index page, basically the page that shows all the posts for a certain user.